# Android: Capture repeatedly same image

Tags: java, android

```
captureBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String folder = "Capture";
                try{
                    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
                    Date currentTime = new Date();
                    String dateString = formatter.format(currentTime);
                    File sdCardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File dirs = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folder);

                    if (!dirs.exists()) {
                        dirs.mkdirs();
                    }
                    container.buildDrawingCache();
                    Bitmap captureView = container.getDrawingCache();
                    FileOutputStream fos;
                    String save;
                    try {
                        save = sdCardPath.getPath() + "/" + folder + "/" + dateString + ".jpg";
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(save);
                        captureView.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                        fos.close();
                        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,
                                Uri.parse("file://" + sdCardPath.getPath() + "/" + folder + "/" + dateString + ".jpg")));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), dateString + ".jpg 저장", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    recentImageName = "file://" + sdCardPath.getPath() + "/" + folder + "/" + dateString + ".jpg";
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });
```

My application has some `EditText`. When I put some words in that `EditText` first and capture through the button, then capture button works well.
But when I delete and put new words in `EditText` and hit the button, the result is the same as first capture.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You are trying to capture the contents of your screen as I understood? And even that you change the EditText value, you get the previous one in the screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `container.destroyDrawingCache()` right after

```
container.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap captureView = container.getDrawingCache();
container.destroyDrawingCache(); //<----
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following thing to take new image every time:

call view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true) each time before taking bitmap cache and view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false) each time after calling view.getDrawingCache().

Example:

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.buildDrawingCache(true);
File imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        "Pictures/image.jpg");
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
view.getDrawingCache(true).compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,
        fileOutputStream);
fileOutputStream.close();
imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

you need setDrawingCacheEnabled(false) after you got the bitmap.